# Cannot set FK constrains in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have a problem that i cant solve right now and i have read similar question but i didnt help me!

I have i Users table and a Books table and i want to set a ONE to ONE relationship between them.

Im trying to set users_id - PK in Users to FK in Books table but it dosent work!

What am i doing wrong?

Please help!

I'll add images for the steps i go through in the same order:

Users table
[image]

Books table, with users_id as index (Non unique)
[image]

Setting upp the constrain for FK
[image]

And at last the ERROR
[image: s]

Comment: Do you already have data in books? (It looks like it.) If so, it all needs to satisfy the constraint.

Comment: actually yes i have, what do you mean by saying "t all needs to satisfy the constraint"?

Comment: You need to make sure all `user_id` values in `books` reflect values already found in `users`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you have a `books` row that does not have a matching `user_id` in the `users` table.

You need to add an user or update the books table first.

If you add a foreign key, you cannot have `null` or `0` values (for `AUTO_INCREMENT` keys) in your books.user_id anymore.

Comment: you mean add a user to the user table?
I already have a user in my user table

Comment: Yes, if you do not have all users added previously. If you do, just assign an already-existing user to the book(s) that have (presumably) 0 or NULL as their user_id value.

Comment: ohh i see now its working, so i have to set up the constrains first before im insert data to the tables? right now user id  was 0 in all columns in Books table

Comment: @Webbie If books.user_id were nullable, you could use NULL to indicate "user unknown". NULL is used for optional references.

Comment: @Victor are you sure about the no NULLs?